# Instantiate class with abstract method

Tags: typescript, tsc, typescript3.0

With Java we can create an instance of the ActionListener class which has an abstract method, something like this (it has been awhile):

```
new ActionListener(){
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     // whatever
  }
}
```

using TypeScript, this is the closest I can get to it:

```
export abstract class ActionListener {

  constructor(f: any) {
    this.actionPerformed = f;
  }

  abstract actionPerformed(input: string): string;

}


new ActionListener(input => {

});
```

there are at least 2 problems:

1. If you use an abstract method with TS, the class has to abstract (I think with Java you could have abstract methods which could be implemented later).
2. I don't know how to tie/tether the type of the input function f, to the type of the parse method.

Does anyone know if there is a way to do this with TS?

Perhaps we can't use `abstract` with TS, and have to do it more like this:

```
type ActionPerformed = (input: string) => string;

export class ActionListener {

  parse: ActionPerformed;

  constructor(f: ActionPerformed) {
    this.parse = f;
  }

}

new ActionListener(input => {
  return 'foo';
});
```

Answer (score 5):

> With Java we can create an instance of the ActionListener class which has an abstract method

No, you *can't* create an instance of a class which has an abstract method. What is supposed to happen when you call that abstract method?

What you *can* do is you can create a *subclass* of that abstract class which implements that abstract method, and you can create an instance *of that subclass*. And that is exactly what your Java code is doing. Your Java code is *not* instantiating an object of `ActionListener`. Your Java code is creating a *subclass* of `ActionListener` which overrides `actionPerformed` and it instantiates *that subclass*.

Now, of course TypeScript supports subclassing, so you can do the exact same thing in TypeScript: create a subclass, override/implement the method, then instantiate *that subclass*:

```
new (class extends ActionListener { 
    actionPerformed(input: string): string {
        return "Hello"
    }
})(input => {
    // Whatever
});
```

or you can do it like so:

```
new (class implements ActionListener {
  actionPerformed(input: string): string {
    return "Hello"
  }
});
```

[Playground here.](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=export%20abstract%20class%20ActionListener%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(f%3A%20any)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.actionPerformed%20%3D%20f%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20abstract%20actionPerformed(input%3A%20string)%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Anew%20(class%20extends%20ActionListener%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20actionPerformed(input%3A%20string)%3A%20string%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%22Hello%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)(input%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Whatever%0D%0A%7D)%3B%0D%0A)

Comment: "No, you can't create an instance of a class which has an abstract method. What is supposed to happen when you call that abstract method?" You can do that in Java. I am not sure what your question means. Each instance creates its own implementation of the abstract method.

Comment: I think `class implements ActionListener` makes more sense, dunno

Comment: In the code you posted, you create a subclass of `ActionListener` which implements `actionPerformed`. This subclass of `ActionListener` is not abstract and it has no abstract methods. Then, you instantiate this subclass. In the code you posted, you *never* instantiate a class which has an abstract method. You instantiate a *subclass of that class*, which has *no* abstract methods. If you know of a way to instantiate a class with an abstract method (without using reflection or bytecode manipulation), feel free to share it; I don't know of any.

Comment: In java every such invocation in code will create a new Anonymous inner class which extends the abstract class so the abstract class will not be instantiated but the Anonymous class instance will be visible. The same is for implemented in that way interfaces.

Comment: And you can do the exact same thing in TypeScript: create a subclass, implement the method, then instantiate *that* subclass which is no longer abstract and thus there is no problem with instantiating it.

Comment: I added an edit with the `implements` way, I assume that is fine too, not sure tho

Comment: Note, however that I fully agree with @Madara: this shouldn't be a class at all, it should be a function (both in Java, and in TypeScript, actually).

Comment: I guess Java can hide classes in newer versions, but any function/method would always be surrounded by a class instance

Answer (score 1):

This is not required in JavaScript or TypeScript. Java has no concept of functions as first class objects, lambdas are just sugar for instantiated objects that implement a functional interface.

As such, the idiomatic way in JS/TS is to not have a class here, but to simply pass a callback function:

```
interface ActionListener {
  (ev: Event) => void;
}

function iNeedAnActionHandler(actionListener: ActionListener) {
  // do stuff
  const ev = new Event(); // whatever
  actionListener(ev);
}
```

No need for clumsy classes and interface implementation just to pass a callback.